# Centering the align environment on the middle column

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I have a set of aligned equations that I would like to provide an `\implies` for down the left hand side. I used this originally:

```
\begin{align}
    (x-1)^2 &= -1    \\
        x-1 &= \pm i \\
          x &= 1 \pm i
\end{align}
```

which results in a centred set of equations. Then added the `\implies` in a left column:

```
\begin{align}
    &          & (x-1)^2 &= -1    \\
    & \implies &     x-1 &= \pm i \\
    & \implies &       x &= 1 \pm i
\end{align}
```

However now the entire environment is shifted to the right. Is there a way to keep the original alignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want **exactly** the same alignment as before, but this time **with** `\implies`, this does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
    (x-1)^2 &= -1     \\ x-1 &= \pm i  \\ x &= 1 \pm i
    \end{align}

    \begin{alignat}{3}
    && (x-1)^2 &= -1      && \phantom{\implies} \\ \implies &&     x-1 &= \pm i   && \\ \implies &&       x &= 1 \pm i &&
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

The idea here is to duplicate the width of `\implies` on the left with a `\phantom{\implies}` on the right, thereby evenly spacing the equation/environment again.

[image: Aligned equation with \implies]

Answer (score 2):

Removing the first alignment character and adding a few `\phantom`s should do the trick. Alternatively you can use `alignat`:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    (x-1)^2 &= -1    \\
        x-1 &= \pm i \\
          x &= 1 \pm i
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \phantom{\implies}    (x-1)^2 &= -1    \\
    \implies\phantom{()^2}    x-1 &= \pm i \\
    \implies\phantom{({}-1)^2}  x &= 1 \pm i
\end{align}

 \begin{alignat}{3}
             && (x-1)^2 &= -1    \\
    \implies &&     x-1 &= \pm i \\
    \implies &&       x &= 1 \pm i
 \end{alignat}
 \end{document}
```